# Pass key-value pairs to function via ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have a function that gets an object from json, and I list its key-value pairs in ng-repeat. It is a form where value is true/false and depending on that, it is checked or not.

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group form-group__bordered"
       ng-repeat="(key, value) in listOfNotificationTypes">

    <label for="inputEmail3">{{ key | trimkey }}</label>

    <div class="checkbox-wrapper">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" ng-checked="{{value}}">
    </div>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-12 clearfix">
        <a href="#" class="btn"
            ng-click="updateNotificationSettings()">
         SAVE
        </a>
    </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

It all works well, but what I want is also to pick up those changed key-value pairs and send them via another function when I hit that SAVE button.

How can I bind the input in ng-model so I have the correct json format passed, like

```
{
   "key1":"value1",
   "key2":"value2",
   "key3":"value3",
    ...
  }
```

I suppose I should use ng-model to capture the data, but do not know how exactly to handle it.

Comment: Do you receive a list or an object? This `{"key1": true,    "key2": false,   key3": false  };` is very diferent from this `[   {key: "key1", value: false},   key: "key2", value: true},   {key: "key3", value: false}  ];`

Comment: It is a json so object, but I would need to pass it exactly like I stated, so basically I just need a list of `{"key": "value","key":"value"}`

Comment: But that is not a list. But ok just use this input instead of yours `<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" ng-model="listOfNotificationTypes[key]">` and in the function updateNotificationSettings the value of `$scope.listOfNotificationTypes` will reflect the values as true or false as Boolean not as string.

Comment: Ok,tnx, will try that, makes sense.

Comment: If needed here a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/uKM1Y2yjnGaqWq2q84Te?p=preview)

Comment: Yeah, this works great, just implemented it. Paste plunker as answer if you want, it solved my probs ;) so you deserve rep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, for your type of of object you will have to use the input like  this.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" ng-model="listOfNotificationTypes[key]">
```

Here is a [**plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/uKM1Y2yjnGaqWq2q84Te?p=preview) demonstrating the implementation.

**Notes:**
Just one few note in the future you may need to transform that object in a list of objects like this

```
[
   {key: "key1", value: false},
   {key: "key2", value: true},
   {key: "key3", value: false}
  ];
```

For that case the code on the front end will be

```
<div class="form-group form-group__bordered" ng-repeat="notification in listOfNotificationTypes">
 <label for="inputEmail3">{{ notification.key }}</label>
  <div class="checkbox-wrapper">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" ng-model="notification.value">
  </div>
</div>
```